# Magento 2 Stop Product Image Compression

Tags: magento2, product-images

compression on Magento 2.x is very strong, so that the quality of product images get really bad in Catalog and Product view.

How can i **disable or stop product image compression ?** currently, Magento 2 have 2 type composition **(PGP GD2 & ImageMagick)**. I want to disable both types.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look in files
`Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php` property `$_quality` (default is 80%)
and
`Magento/Framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php` lines from 165-176 (for .PNG files compression is set to maximum)

These two places are responsible for images quality.

Comment: Yes, That i know and try it, but it's not getting a proper result. I want to disable permanently. Didi you know in which file compression code available??